# Automatically Drop Old Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008, interatively.  When using SQL Server Management Studio, every very time I make an update I have to manually refresh the Programmability folder, then right-click, then delete, then OK.  I could also run a query to drop the stored procedure as well.

Is there some function I can drop into stored procedure when first executing the code (from the actual stored procedure code, not the exec command) that will check to see if there is an existing stored procedure, if so, then `DROP` and replace with the new code?

Or, is this a bad idea due to version control?

Comment: Why not use the [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx) syntax when writing stored procedures?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add this to the top of your procedure script. (just replace the ownerName and ProcName with the real values.

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[OwnerName].[ProcName]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [OwnerName].[ProcName]
GO
```

Alternatively you can write `ALTER PROC`, but this may be an issue if you're saving your work as a script to be later deployed to a databases that may not have the procedure

As an aside you can always have SQL server generate this for you by right clicking on an existing procedure and selecting `Script Stored Procedure as -> DROP and CREATE to -> ...`

You could also use the Template Explorer <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+T</kbd> and use the Drop Stored Procedure template (below is the default) and then use the `Query -> Specify Values for Template Parameters`

```
-- =======================================================
-- Drop Stored Procedure 
-- =======================================================

-- Drop stored procedure if it already exists
IF EXISTS (
  SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES 
   WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = N'<Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>'
     AND SPECIFIC_NAME = N'<Procedure_Name, sysname, Procedure_Name>' 
)
   DROP PROCEDURE <Schema_Name, sysname, Schema_Name>.<Procedure_Name, sysname, Procedure_Name>
GO
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `ALTER` instead of `CREATE` so you do modify the existing stored procedure, you don't have to drop then re-create.

Comment: The alter will also maintain any specific permissions you granted on the proc.

Answer (score 2):

First check the existance:

```
if exists(select * from sys.procedures where object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.procname'))
  drop procedure dbo.procname
```

**but** doing that you kill the already granted or denied permissions on procedute, so - the better way not to use drop/create scenario, but check for NON-existance and `alter`:

```
if NOT exists(select * from sys.procedures where object_id = OBJECT_ID('dbo.procname'))
  EXEC('CREATE PROC dbo.procname as')
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.procname
...
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio I right click on the stored procedure - select script stored procedures as - select drop and create to  - new query window editor.

We already have this code in all of our procedures as already mentioned above:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[Name].[spName]') AND type in (N'P', N'PC'))
DROP PROCEDURE [Name].[spName]
GO
```

So I can make a change to the procedure in the query window, execute it from the command toolbar to pick up my changes.  Then I go to the stored procedure and right click to execute it.  No refreshes or deletes are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

When I create my stored procedure scripts I often precede each stored procedure definition with something like the following (I've seen variations):

```
PRINT 'Creating stored procedure "sp_tbl_multipart_msg_part_move".'
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id('sp_tbl_multipart_msg_part_add'))
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.sp_tbl_multipart_msg_part_move
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.sp_tbl_multipart_msg_part_move
--SP Code Goes Here
END
GO
```

Then I can just run the whole script every time and it drops the procs before recreating them.

I think this is what you mean.